# React Native API Fetch

Tags: javascript, fetch, react-native

I'm trying to use fetch api in react native using following code snippet. Whenever I try to console.log the API data array it always comes up 'undefined'?!?!

**Home.JS**

```
import api from '../components/api';

class Home extends Component {

constructor(props){
 super(props);
 this.state = {
  profile: []
 }
}

componentWillMount(){
 api.getProfile().then((res) => {
  this.setState({
    profile: res.profile
   })
 });
}
render() {
 console.log("Profile: ", this.state.profile); // Console Out API Data
 return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Text style={styles.welcome}></Text>
  </View>
  );
 }
};
```

**API.JS**

```
var api = {
 getProfile(){
    var url = 'https://api.lootbox.eu/xbl/us/Food%20Market/profile';
    return fetch(url).then((res) => res.json());
 }
};

module.exports = api;
```

Comment: try to `console.log` the `res.data` instead of `res.profile`

Comment: no luck with this solution :/

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is using `componentWillMount` to fetch data. Check these [part](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount) of the docs:

> componentWillMount() is invoked immediately before mounting occurs. It
>   is called before render(), therefore setting state in this method will
>   not trigger a re-rendering. Avoid introducing any side-effects or
>   subscriptions in this method.
>
> This is the only lifecycle hook called on server rendering. Generally,
>   we recommend using the constructor() instead.

Basically, you need to use `componentDidMount`. See [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount):

> componentDidMount() is invoked immediately after a component is
>   mounted. Initialization that requires DOM nodes should go here. If you
>   need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place to
>   instantiate the network request. Setting state in this method will
>   trigger a re-rendering.

By the way, if you are doing it this way (directly into the component) you need to make sure to handle the case where the response comes and the component has been unmounted. In this case, you can use `componentWillUnmount` to cancel any requests before the component is unmounted.

Answer (score 0):

i hope its not too late, i had same issue and stumble on your question.
all you have to do is change `res.profile` to `res`. am sure you dont have `profile` data in your *json responce*

```
 componentWillMount(){
      api.getProfile().then((res) => {
      this.setState({
       profile: res
    })
  });
}
```

i hope this helps someone in need.